# Do javascript functions have referential transparency with mutable state?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, web-worker

[Reading through this article on Javascript Functional Programming](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/functional-javascript) and it mentions **Referential Transparency** being defined as:

> Referential transparency: The function always gives the same return value for the same arguments. This means that the function cannot depend on any mutable state.

IIUC Javascript functions satisfy this requirement even if they depend on mutable state, because two functions cannot operate on shared state even if they are running at the same time?

Comment: if one function can cause the other return value to change, then no.

Comment: What has this to do with web workers? Can you give some examples?

Comment: Not 100% sure I understand the question, but consider `let x = 0; const fn = a => a + x;`, so `fn` does not qualify because it depends on mutable (or reassignable), non-argument `x`.

Comment: But can x be redefined while `fn` is running within any javascript engine?  If a web worker could redefine `x` while `fn` is inflight then the referential transparency principle would be violated.

Comment: @Ole javascript is single threaded so it's hard to see how two functions can simultaneously operate on the shared data.

Comment: No, not *while* `fn` is running, but that's not something that matters, I think? It's just the fact that `x` can be reassigned, regardless of the time at which it can be reassigned

Comment: The "referential transparency" definition is ambiguous or wrong in this case, did it mean "pure function"?

Comment: If the function does depend on any external variables (be them modified in the same thread or not) that might change from all call to another, then the function is not pure.

Comment: @CertainPerformance it does matter from a concurrency point of view, because if it were true, then we would have situations that are far less predictable than when its false.  At least since it's not true, we can track all activity that mutates x, and reason about it.

Comment: @Cristy I think the referential transparency definition is wrong in the Javascript context.  For a Java context it is correct because x could be changed by two separate threads while both threads are running functions leading to race conditions, but with Javascript this is impossible IIUC.

Comment: While knowing whether "shared mutable state" is something to worry about for a given environment is certainly important to keep in mind, that's separate from the issue I was referencing, which is - whether or not `x` can be changed while `fn` is running (even if most times it can't be, I'm not even sure when it *could* be), the output of `fn` still depends on `x`, which is not an argument, therefore `fn` is impure (or, not referentially transparent?) regardless.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I see what you are saying and agree.  I'm more worried about whether web workers could make the assumptions of the possibility of x being modified while the function is running true, but IIUC that's impossible.  Since it's not true then the goal of referential transparency, which is to provide consistent output for consistent input remains intact, because x cannot change while the function is running.

Comment: I think the difference is that arguments are explicit inputs, while `x` is simply an outside variable. It's useful for a *caller* of `fn` to know that `fn(5)` will always return the same input regardless of state. Although the main concern other programming languages have with *shared mutable state* isn't a problem for JS due to being single-threaded, pure functions can still make code easier to reason about.

Comment: Yup - We are on the same page.  So it seems it just depends on your viewpoint.  Bascially for javascript `fn(5, x)` is the same as `fn(5)` which closes over x and will provide the same answer always for the same value of x.  It's just important to understand that we are viewing x as part of the input to `fn`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer You can have two threads by creating a new separate window and storing values in the localStorage. I actually had to deal with race conditions before with two windows reading and writing values in localStorage.

Comment: That's interesting @Derek朕會功夫 (and sounds like a difficult issue). Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I don't think those are threads technically speaking, but processes.  Chrome runs each window or tab in its own process, so that the entire brower does not crash if the process crashes.  Threads run within a process.  Still very good to know.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Ole If one window opens up another window and one window crashes, the other window will also crash since Chrome will not create separate processes for every single tab. Open up the “Chrome Task Manager” (or whatever that’s called) and you can see that they share the same process indicated by the line to the left.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 AHA!  Just looked it up and you are right!  In order for a new process to be created, the domain has to be different for the tab window.  That's good to know.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Ole JavaScript is an amazing language with a lot of weird behaviors that you might not expect :)

Comment: Hehe - Yeah - What is `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to summarize our discussion, yes Javascript functions do have referential transparency as long as the mutable state they depend on does not change.

In other words the same output will be provided for the same input while the mutable state that the function depends on is held constant.

This seems somewhat obvious, but for Javascript and functional programming its an important concept / realization because Javascript cannot run the function in two threads at the same time.  If we could change the state that the function depends on while the function is running we could create race conditions that are hard to reason about and that would make the function results unpredictable, which is what we are trying to avoid with referential transparency.

For example a function `fn(5)`, that depends on mutable state `x` will always return the same result for the same input, as long as x does not change.

In non Javascript environments it's possible to change x while the function is running, so two invocations of `fn(5)` could return different results.

With Javascript if `fn(5)` returns a different result, we know exactly why.  It's because `x` was changed between invocations of `fn(5)`.